# Nautilus, mount ISO file with right-click menu

Tags: gnome, automounting, nautilus, iso

I am using Nautilus now, and back then when i was using Ubuntu i could right-click on an ISO file and automount it without the need to issue any command.

But now i am using Nautilus in Archlinux and it seems that it doesn't have the needed plugin for that to work, is anybody know what is the package name, or what should i do in order to get that feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a Great [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mounting_images_as_user) on how to do that, (it is in the Arch wiki but it works with all nautilus at every distro).

- Install the `nautilus-actions` and `fuseiso` packages with you package manager.
- Create a file with the a name like `nautilus-actions-iso-mount.sh` where ever you want (e.g `/usr/bin/`), and paste in it the following:

> #! /bin/bash
>
> FILE=`basename "$1"` MOUNTPOINT="$HOME/Desktop/$FILE"
>
> fuseiso -p "$1" "$MOUNTPOINT"

- Create another file with a name like `nautilus-actions-iso-umount.sh` where ever you want (e.g `/usr/bin/`), and paste in it the following:

> #! /bin/bash
>
> FILE=`basename "$1"` MOUNTPOINT="$HOME/Desktop/$FILE"
>
> fusermount -u "$MOUNTPOINT"

- Make the files executeables: with  `chmod +x /<path_to_scripts>/nautilus-actions-iso-*`

And finelly do the follwing in order to add the scripts you have created before to your nautilus menu:

start nautilus-actions-config (System -> Preferences -> Nautilus Actions Configuration).

Add a new action with the following settings:

> ```
>         Label: Mount ISO
>        Icon: A symbol of your choice (eg: gtk-cdrom)
>        Path: /<path_to_scripts>/nautilus-actions-iso-mount.sh
>        Parameters: %F
>        Working directory: %d
>        Basenames: *.iso ; *.nrg ; *.bin ; *.img ; *.mdf (for each add a seperated entry)
>        Match case: "must match one of"
>        Mimetypes: */*
> ```

With this action you can mount ISO-images to your Desktop. It will create an folder in ~/Desktop with the name of the iso. fuseiso will mount the iso to this folder.

And a second one:

> ```
>    Label: Unmount ISO
>    Icon: A symbol of your choice (eg: gtk-cdrom)
>    Path: /<path_to_scripts>/nautilus-actions-iso-umount.sh
>    Parameters: %F
>    Working directory: %d
>    Basenames: *.iso ; *.nrg ; *.bin ; *.img ; *.mdf (for each add a seperated entry)
>    Match case: "must match one of"
>    Mimetypes: */*
> ```

This second action will unmount the mounted iso and remove the folder from the desktop.

Sometimes you have to logout to be able to mount any image of the given types simply by right clicking it in Nautilus and selecting Mount ISO. To unmount it again, just right click the corresponding folder on your desktop and select Unmount ISO.

And there you are, it works flawlessly. 
I have tested it with Gnome 3.

Comment: good one Hanan! :-)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/), but let me share what worked for me using [openSUSE Leap 42.2](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:42.2) with [GNOME 3.20](https://www.gnome.org/news/2016/03/gnome-3-20-released/).

[openSUSE](https://www.opensuse.org/) has a package called [`gnome-disk-utility`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/gnome-disk-utility). Installing it makes available the [Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) app and the ability to mount ISO images from [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files).

With `gnome-disk-utility` installed, mounting an ISO image is an easy task:

1. Open Nautilus
2. Browse to an ISO file and right click on it
3. Click on Open With Other Application
4. Choose Disk Image Mounter
5. You will find the mounted image clicking on Other locations in the Nautilus sidebar

To unmount the image, just click on the Unmount icon towards its entry at Other locations.

Curiously, it seems that those same instructions apply to [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-disk-utility) and [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/gnome-disk-utility). I discovered Disks at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/644781/560233). So maybe Arch Linux has a package (or whatever you name it) called `gnome-disk-utility` too and you could try doing that.

I hope that helps anyone heading to this page (as did I).

**[Edit]** from [Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168460):

> I just realized, there a thing called "gnome-disk-image-mounter" but
>   for whatever reason it was hidden and I was unable to set it as
>   default for images.
>
> I think this is pretty much solved, thanks for your help.

Comment: CentOS 7 has also a gnome-disk-utility in the base repo.

Comment: in arch too its under gnome-disk-utility

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking of mounting iso in gnome, then there is this link http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mount-isos-easely-in-gnome-nautilus.html

Or better

Download this nautilus-mount-image (tar.gz file) from http://mundogeek.net/nautilus-scripts/#nautilus-mount-image

This program adds a new entry to the contextual menu which allows us to mount and unmount the selected CD or DVD (iso) image. Its a python script actually as an extension to nautilus menu.

Extract the tar.gz file into a temporary directory and install the nautilus-mount-image.py script by running

```
$ gmake
$ gmake check
$ sudo gmake update-po
$ sudo gmake install
```

After this, try right click and check if the menu is updated or restart gnome (logoff and login). This menu option will be available for all users on the system.

Comment: @Hanan.H  was my post useful to you?

Comment: I will check that soon and report back, Thanks.